# Is it prohibited to name father's name to the child in Islam?

Tags: sharia, hadith, source-identification, naming

It is better to give a different name to the child. We have also heard the arabs name in Prophet's time(now too) that XXX ibnu YYY. I'm also remembering a hadith that at judgement day Allah will call all the people with their names associated with their father's name.

I heard a new thing(for me) that muslims are prohibited to name father's name to the child. Is it so?

> **If yes**, please provide the hadith for that.
>
> **If not**, please mention the person(prophets/sahabas/popular scholar
>   only) who is/was named exactly his father's name.

**EDIT:**

---

I don't have any proof for prohibiting of naming father's name to son. That is why I asked for a source if it is true. If Islam allows the father to name his son exactly his name, I asked for if any scholars/prophets/sahabas done like that or not. ie, XXX ibnu XXX.

Comment: I believe its supposed to be the job of who made the claim (that naming sons after fathers is haram) to provide evidence.

Comment: I have not heard of this, but I did see many people being named after their grandpas. Whoever says its haram has to prove what he claims.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is never forbidden, for example the name of a son of Imam Hassan peace be upon him, the grandson of the holy prophet peace be upon him and his household and the older son of Imam Ali and the holiness Fatima peace be upon them, was also Hassan, then called Hassan ibnul Hassan (الحسن ابن الحسن) or [الحسن المثنی](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AB%D9%86%D9%89). Even a son of him was also named Hassan (الحسن بن الحسن بن السحسن) or [الحسن المثلث](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AB%D9%84%D8%AB).

Although not directly answering your question but for the sake of completeness it is not forbidden to name two sons a same name, like Imam Hussain peace be upon him, another grandson of the holy prophet peace be upon him and his household gave three of his sons a same name, Ali, so we have Ali Akbar (the older Ali), Ali Awsat (the middle Ali), and Ali Asqar (the younger Ali), apparently the first and the third being martyred in Karbala. Even Imam Hussain's daughters had the same name Fatimah, Al-Fatimah al-Kobra and Al-Fatimah al-Soqra.

Answer (score -1):

Well it is not really forbidden because Islamic leaders during the middle ages and recently have the same names like Mohammad II of Jordan (For Example)

Comment: Please note that many Muslim leaders were referred to by names which were chosen for them during their reign, not the name they were named with by their father for example the Abbasid Caliph al-Mutawwakil's (or more exactly al-Mutawwakil bil-Laah) real name was Ja'afar ibn Muhammad (al-Mu'tassim) ibn Haroon ar-Rasheed. Further any leader we may today call by Muhammad "X" or Sulayman "X" etc. was hardly called this way by his surroundings and contemporary people.